# possible to capture function parameters in groups

Tags: typescript

suppose I define two types:

```
interface a{
name: string;
color: string;
}

interface b{
age: number;
address: string;
}
```

can we create a function:

```
function pass(//capture in groups A: a and B: b){
  console.log("group A", A);
  console.log("group B", B);
}  
  

const name = "new";
const age= 32;
const color = "red";
color address = "home";

calling: pass(name, age, address, color)
```

would output:

```
group A {name: "new", color: "red"}
group B {age: 32, address: "home"}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is capture the parameters passed by the user into groups
i.e. it groups all parameters passed in a function according to the type specified in the
function definition.

Comment: Not without writing the code for it. TS only exists at compiletime, it will not modify the arguments you pass at runtime.

Comment: @VLAZ , code as in manually grouping them? I wanted to make it dynamic for any number/type of parameters with respect to the interface

Comment: What you pass in does *not* respect the interface. You pass in primitive strings and numbers and the expectation is to combine these values into an interface. And having it "dynamic for any number/type of parameters" is also a huge no-go: once a *value* is passed as an argument, you cannot determine what *variable name* it was under. so `pass(name, color)` is *indistinguishable* at call time from `pass(apple, banana)` or even straight literals `pass("Fred", "chucknorris")`

Comment: okay, but, say I capture like this: function({name, color, age, address}), is there a direct way to destructure using an interface like this pseudocode?: `const val={name, age, color, address}; const  x : aInterface= val;` which would only destructure properties in the `aInterface` into x

Comment: That would only allow you to now have labels with values. It will not magically convert those into separate objects that follow the TS interfaces. There is no way to do this except writing explicit runtime code that will do this. Which, in turn, requires runtime knowledge of what the interface is as that information is stripped away after compilation.